# Using object lock in multi threading java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program to renew service using multi threading.

My program have 1 thread for retrieving subscribers (Retriever) then push to queue, and some threads for getting subs from queue to renew service (Worker). If renew error, the Retriever will push it to queue again. 
The Retriever loop infinite, if queue is empty, it'll push subscriber into queue, otherwise, it'll sleep in some seconds.
If nothing in queue, Worker'll sleep in some seconds.
My problem is: sometimes, a subscriber's service is renewed multiple by multiple Workers. I try to use hashmap lock but it still wrong.

This is my code for object lock:

```
public class ExtendServiceLockObj {
    static  Map lock = new HashMap();

    static synchronized boolean isLocking(String msisdn) {
        if (lock.containsKey(msisdn)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static synchronized void put(String msisdn, long id) {
        lock.put(msisdn, new Long(id));
    }   

    static synchronized void remove(String msisdn) {
        lock.remove(msisdn);
    }
}
```

This is my Worker code:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    -- if it can pull subscriber from queue
                    if (ExtendServiceLockObj.isLocking(msisdn)) {
                            logger.error("Renew_SERVICE (" + msisdn
                                    + ") locked");                          
                            continue;
                    }else{
                        -- Renew service
                        try {
                            ExtendServiceLockObj.put(msisdn, id);
                            -- do something
                            -- if renew successfully
                            ExtendServiceLockObj.remove(msisdn);
                        }catch (Exception){
                            ExtendServiceLockObj.remove(msisdn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){                
                    -- write log
                    ExtendServiceLockObj.remove(msisdn);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception ){
            -- write log            
        }
}
```

My Retriever code:

```
try {
    while (running) {
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                while (running) {
                -- query database to get subscribers
                -- try to enqueue
                }
            }catch (Exception ){}
        }
        Thread.sleep(interval);
    }
}catch (Exception e){
}
```

I use ArrayBlockingQueue for my program.

> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE, true);

Sometime i can see

> Renew_SERVICE (#msisdn) locked

in log file.

Can you give me some advice. Sorry for my english.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a `BlockingQueue`? This interface has been designed for such scenarios

Comment: Seems like you can make use of the [Producer/Consumer pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i also use ArrayBlockingQueue for the Retriever

Comment: Seems like something you should look into Nashorn javascript into. It is Java's built in JavaScript engine. You can expose your threaded classes with callback interfaces to javascript have the script engine take care of the queueing for you, just program your classes in nonblocking asynchronous way. Based on all the sleeps, exceptions, and queues and maps in this code, it seems you have limited experience in nonblocking asynchronous programming and could benefit from looking into it..